# EntityFrameworkCore.InMemory System.ArgumentException

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, entity-framework, entity-framework-core, in-memory-database

I am working on ASP.NET sample projects in Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2017. The project I am currently working on was running fine yesterday. When I opened the project today, I immediately receive a message box:

> The project system has encountered an error.
>
> An element with the same key but different value already exists. Key: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.InMemory
>
> A diagnostic log has been written:

```
=====================
Crippling
System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. ---> System.ArgumentException: An element with the same key but a different value already exists. Key: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.InMemory
   at System.Collections.Immutable.ImmutableDictionary`2.HashBucket.Add(TKey key, TValue value, IEqualityComparer`1 keyOnlyComparer, IEqualityComparer`1 valueComparer, KeyCollisionBehavior behavior, OperationResult& result)
   at System.Collections.Immutable.ImmutableDictionary`2.AddRange(IEnumerable`1 items, MutationInput origin, KeyCollisionBehavior collisionBehavior)
   at System.Collections.Immutable.ImmutableDictionary`2.AddRange(IEnumerable`1 pairs, Boolean avoidToHashMap)
   at System.Collections.Immutable.ImmutableDictionary`2.AddRange(IEnumerable`1 pairs)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ProjectSystem.Designers.ProjectBuildSubscriptionService.UpdateRuleSnapshotCore(IProjectVersionedValue`1 source, String ruleName, IRule rule, ImmutableDictionary`2 items, ImmutableDictionary`2 properties, ImmutableList`1 recentItemRenames, IProjectChangeDiff& diff)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ProjectSystem.Designers.ProjectRuleSubscriptionServiceBase`1.UpdateSnapshotCoreAsync(TSource source, IImmutableSet`1 subscribedElements, IProjectVersionedValue`1 previousResult)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ProjectSystem.Designers.CustomizableBlockSubscriberBase`3.<UpdateSnapshotAsync>d__28.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ProjectSystem.Designers.CustomizableBlockSubscriberBase`3.<>c__DisplayClass27_0.<<Initialize>b__1>d.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Threading.JoinableTask.<JoinAsync>d__76.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Threading.JoinableTask`1.<JoinAsync>d__3.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ProjectSystem.Designers.CustomizableBlockSubscriberBase`3.<<Initialize>b__27_0>d.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ProjectSystem.DataflowExtensions.<>c__DisplayClass23_0`2.<<CreateSelfFilteringTransformBlock>b__0>d.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ProjectSystem.CommonProjectSystemTools.Rethrow(Exception ex)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ProjectSystem.ProjectErrorReporting.<>c__DisplayClass6_0.<SubmitErrorReport>b__0()
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ProjectSystem.ExceptionFilter.<>c__DisplayClass2_0.<Guard>b__0()
   at GuardMethodClass.GuardMethod(Func`1 , Func`2 , Func`2 )
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
---> (Inner Exception #0) System.ArgumentException: An element with the same key but a different value already exists. Key: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.InMemory
   at System.Collections.Immutable.ImmutableDictionary`2.HashBucket.Add(TKey key, TValue value, IEqualityComparer`1 keyOnlyComparer, IEqualityComparer`1 valueComparer, KeyCollisionBehavior behavior, OperationResult& result)
   at System.Collections.Immutable.ImmutableDictionary`2.AddRange(IEnumerable`1 items, MutationInput origin, KeyCollisionBehavior collisionBehavior)
   at System.Collections.Immutable.ImmutableDictionary`2.AddRange(IEnumerable`1 pairs, Boolean avoidToHashMap)
   at System.Collections.Immutable.ImmutableDictionary`2.AddRange(IEnumerable`1 pairs)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ProjectSystem.Designers.ProjectBuildSubscriptionService.UpdateRuleSnapshotCore(IProjectVersionedValue`1 source, String ruleName, IRule rule, ImmutableDictionary`2 items, ImmutableDictionary`2 properties, ImmutableList`1 recentItemRenames, IProjectChangeDiff& diff)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ProjectSystem.Designers.ProjectRuleSubscriptionServiceBase`1.UpdateSnapshotCoreAsync(TSource source, IImmutableSet`1 subscribedElements, IProjectVersionedValue`1 previousResult)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ProjectSystem.Designers.CustomizableBlockSubscriberBase`3.<UpdateSnapshotAsync>d__28.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ProjectSystem.Designers.CustomizableBlockSubscriberBase`3.<>c__DisplayClass27_0.<<Initialize>b__1>d.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Threading.JoinableTask.<JoinAsync>d__76.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Threading.JoinableTask`1.<JoinAsync>d__3.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ProjectSystem.Designers.CustomizableBlockSubscriberBase`3.<<Initialize>b__27_0>d.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ProjectSystem.DataflowExtensions.<>c__DisplayClass23_0`2.<<CreateSelfFilteringTransformBlock>b__0>d.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ProjectSystem.CommonProjectSystemTools.Rethrow(Exception ex)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ProjectSystem.ProjectErrorReporting.<>c__DisplayClass6_0.<SubmitErrorReport>b__0()
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ProjectSystem.ExceptionFilter.<>c__DisplayClass2_0.<Guard>b__0()
   at GuardMethodClass.GuardMethod(Func`1 , Func`2 , Func`2 )<---

===================
```

It also caused some other problems such as all of my using directives for the System and Microsoft namespaces giving errors:

> The type or namespace name 'System' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Since these directives are still working fine for other projects, I suspect they will subside when the EntityFramework problem is fixed.

I have tried restarting both Visual Studio and my computer and have tried building the project anyway. I am not able to add references to the project. I receive message boxes:

> A task was canceled
>
> The operation could not be completed

References to namespaces within the project are still working fine.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Close VS.
2. Open your project file (`csproj` file or `project.json`) via
   an external text editor and remove duplicated package references.
3. Reopen VS. All should work fine.

If a `csproj` file format is used -  look for the lines like this:

```
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.InMemory" Version="1.1.1" />
```